# Does there exist a sequence on the unit sphere which converges to zero under compact operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let  $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and $T: X \rightarrow Y$ be compact operator (between Banach spaces).

Question: Does there always exist a sequence $x_n$ of norm $1$ such that $T(x_n)$ converges to zero?

If we assume $X$ to be reflexive, this is the case: Choose a sequence on the unit sphere which converges weakly to zero. The compact operator $T$ then maps this sequence to a sequence converging to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your claim were false, $T$ would need to be injective.

Furthermore, it would follow that the constant
$$
C := \inf_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|
$$
is positive. From this, it follows that $T(X)$ is closed and $T : X \to T(X)$ is a bijective linear map between Banach spaces and thus an isomorphism of Banach spaces.

But $T(B_1 (0))$ is precompact, so that $B_1 (0)$ is itself precompact. It follows that $X$ is finite dimensional, a contradiction.

Hence, we can always find a sequence with the desired properties.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the closedness of $T(X)$ follows from $C>0$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future readers... By knowing that $C>0$ we have a constant such that $\forall x\in X, ||Tx|| \geq C||x||$. Indeed, if $||x||=1$, then it's clear that $||Tx||>C$. Additionally, if $x$ is nonzero and $||x||\neq 1$ we have that $||Tx/||x|| || \geq C$, thus $||Tx|| \geq C||x||$. Now, why is the range closed? Assume you have a convergent sequence $(Tx_n)_{n\geq 1}$. Then, we have $||Tx_n-Tx_m|| \geq C||x_n-x_m||$, which implies that $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy. Since $X$ is Banach, there is a limit $x$ s.t. $x_n\to x$. Now, notice that $Tx \in R(T)$ and $Tx_n \to Tx$. Thus, $R(T)$ is closed.